# Question about vectorizing colors in Bokeh

Tags: python, colors, vectorization, bokeh

Here you can see an example on "Vectorizing colors", this is the code:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps/first_steps_5.html

```
import random

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

# generate some data (1-10 for x, random values for y)
x = list(range(0, 26))
y = random.sample(range(0, 100), 26)

# generate list of rgb hex colors in relation to y
colors = ["#%02x%02x%02x" % (255, int(round(value * 255 / 100)), 255) for value in y]

# create new plot
p = figure(
    title="Vectorized colors example",
    sizing_mode="stretch_width",
    max_width=500,
    plot_height=250,
)

# add circle and line renderers
line = p.line(x, y, line_color="blue", line_width=1)
circle = p.circle(x, y, fill_color=colors, line_color="blue", size=15)

# show the results
show(p)
```

My question is about this line:

```
colors = ["#%02x%02x%02x" % (255, int(round(value * 255 / 100)), 255) for value in y]
```

After learning about hex and printing the variable "colors" I see this generates a list of colors for Bokeh, what I don't understand is after the for loop we don't have the variable y anywhere in this list (if I am correct), just strings, so How does Bokeh know what value to use for each y?

I mean, here:

```
circle = p.circle(x, y, fill_color=colors, line_color="blue", size=15)
```

We are sending a list of strings to "fill_color", but in this list there is not anything about y.

This is a bit difficult to show the first example, Can anybody show a simpler example to modify the color as function of one of the variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the example you shared three list are genereated with 26 elements each (`x`, `y` and `colors`).

Bokeh takes it by order.

The bokeh library takes the first hex string of the `colors`-list to use this color to draw the first circle defind by the first item of `x` and `y`. Then it takes the second hex string to draw the second cirlce and so on.

If you change an element by hand, you will see how it works. If you add the next line right after defining `colors` the fifth element is draw in blue (keep in mind zero indexing).

```
colors[4] = '#33ffff'
```

[image: change on item 4 of the color list]

**Edit**

I try to explain it in a different way. In the next example I use a pandas Dataframe to store the data in a table. The logic is still the same.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(26)))
df.index.name = 'x'
df['y'] = random.sample(range(0, 100), 26)
df['colors'] = ["#%02x%02x%02x" % (255, int(round(value * 255 / 100)), 255) for value in df['y']]

>>>df
    y   colors
x             
0  23  #ff3bff
1   8  #ff14ff
2  39  #ff63ff
3  40  #ff66ff
4   4  #ff0aff
```

Now you can see, that each `x` and `y` have a color string. Now the first circle is drawn by the information of the first row. The Second circle is drawn by the information of the second row. And so on.

If you now define a bokeh figure, the code looks close to your example and the figure looks the same (except the random `y`).

```
# create new plot
p = figure(
    title="Vectorized colors example",
    sizing_mode="stretch_width",
    max_width=500,
    plot_height=250,
)

# add circle and line renderers
line = p.line(x='x', y='y', source=df, line_color="blue", line_width=1)
circle = p.circle(x='x', y='y', fill_color='colors', source=df, line_color="blue", size=15)

# show the results
show(p)
```

Comment: I think it just applies the colors to the y variable by default.

Comment: I hope my edit helps. Please check it out.